# How can I make a validation message for an @HTML.TextBox() appear?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following snap code :

My ViewClass look like this:

```
...
<%=Html.ValidationSummary() %>
...

<div class="editor-field-short">
   <%: Html.TextBox("Identity", Model.Identity, new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
      { "class", "textbox DependantIdPassportTextBox" },
      { "data-val", "true" },
      { "data-val-required", "Please enter the Identity Number" },                     
   },)%>
  <div class="editor-container"><%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Identity)%></div>
</div>
```

Controller Class

```
public ActionResult ValidateMember(String Identity)
{
...
var memberIdNo = MemberProfileService.GetProfileByIdNumber(Identity);
 if (memberIdNo == null)
 {
   ModelState.AddModelError("Identity", "Member does not exist");
   return View("Index");
 }
 ...
```

So if MemberIdNo ==Null is true..the error message "Member does not exist" doesnt get displayed in my ViewClass.

updated:

So I get the following :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
on this line: <%: Html.TextBox("Identity", Model.Identity, new Dictionary

Comment: Is this inside a partial or editor template?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov its inside a partial template

Comment: What's the value of the `name` attribute of the generated input field from the TextBox helper?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I used : <%: Html.TextBox**For**(...)  and removed this line :

```
<div class="editor-container"><%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Identity)%></div>
```

as every validation message is printed on : **<%=Html.ValidationSummary() %>**